# How to get fields without access in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, fields, access, outputfield

I have a set of field names that I am getting from a FieldSet. And some fields are inaccessible (I closed access for them). But I have to get these fields and output them to the form. How can i do this in LWC?

Comment: why did you close access to fields if you need them for a form? Or are you suggesting you want to put fields on a LWC and have it display based on profile settings (read-only vs. edit) on the form?

Comment: because this is a part of my task) I'm just learning) I need to output field without access